# TinyMCE - IE8 Error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, tinymce

I'm testing my page in a bunch of browsers and in IE 8 i get the following error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 20:03:46 UTC


Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 1314
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.1.93/JS/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js
```

Any idea on how to fix this? My TinyMCE version is:

```
majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '3.9',
releaseDate : '2010-09-08',
```

My init is:

```
tinyMCE.init({
'mode' : 'exact', 
'elements' : 'EDITOR', 
'auto_focus' : 'EDITOR', 
'theme' : 'advanced', 
'plugins' : 'safari,save,preview,table,paste,insertdatetime', 
'height' : h, 
'width' : w, 
'cleanup_on_startup' : true, 
'fix_list_elements' : true, 
'fix_table_elements' : true, 
'fix_nesting' : false, 
'theme_advanced_layout_manager' : 'SimpleLayout', 
'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : 'top', 
'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' : 'left', 
forced_root_block : '', 
'theme_advanced_buttons1' : 'save, cancel, |, fontselect, fontsizeselect, formatselect, |, backcolor, forecolor, |, selectall, cut, copy, paste, pastetest, pasteword, |, undo, redo', 
'theme_advanced_buttons2' : 'anchor, link, unlink, |, bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, sub, sup, |, numlist, bullist, charmap, |, outdent, indent, |, justifyleft, justifycenter, justifyright, justifyfull, |, insertdate, inserttime', 
'theme_advanced_buttons3' : 'tablecontrols', 
'theme_advanced_font_sizes' : '8pt,9pt,10pt,11pt,12pt,14pt,16pt,17pt,18pt,19pt,20pt,25pt,30pt,35pt,40pt', 
'theme_advanced_buttons3_add' : '|, code', 
'end' : 'end', 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My height and width were messed up. The function I used to get h and w worked everywhere just fine everywhere but in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error in IE8. Except the cause of mine was that I was not specifying a height/width at all. Even though it was still loading correctly, and adopting the size of the text box that it converted, it still threw an "invalid argument" exception.

Fixed it by adding this code to the init:

```
$('#' + textAreaID).tinymce({

    ...

    height: $('#' + textAreaID).outerHeight(),
    width: $('#' + textAreaID).outerWidth()
});
```

(using jQuery syntax)